# How do I populate a form via ajax that will update a model?

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, django

I'm trying to load a blank form on a page (with form hidden) and populate and show it iff the user clicks a jobnum button.

As far as I have found when reading I need to pass the primary key when rendering the form but of course I cannot pass the primary key until the user clicks the button. But I need to render the form on page load so obviously it won't already have a pk associated with it since the user hasn't clicked the button yet.

I was able to get the pk by passing my information via the following jquery and view.py:

```
$('#editjob').click(function(){
    var a = document.getElementById('jobNum').textContent
    $.ajax({
    url: "editjob",
    data: {'jobnum':a},
    success: function(data) {
        alert(data);
        // $(".mydiv").append(data);
    },
    });
});


def editjob(request):
  if request.is_ajax():
    jobnum = request.GET.get('jobnum')
    job_list = Job.objects.filter(jobnum=jobnum)
    json_data = serializers.serialize('json', job_list)
    a = json.loads(json_data)
    a = a[0]['pk'] #that's our pk!
  return JsonResponse(a,safe=False)
```

This just alerts me with the pk.

I then figured I'd need to do something like this:

```
  j = Job.objects.get(pk=a)     
  editJobForm = JobForm(request.POST or None, prefix='edit',instance=j)
  if editJobForm.is_valid():
        frm_jobnum = editJobForm.cleaned_data.get("jobnum")
        frm_pm = editJobForm.cleaned_data.get("pm")
        # other clean data's redacted
        instance = editJobForm.save()
        instance.save()
```

Then problem is of course that I cannot pass 'editJobForm' into context and then render it on my main page because when the page first loads the user won't have clicked the button that triggers the ajax request which gets the requisite pk.

Another attempt I tried was to render the form in it's own page `editjob.html` and then include it in my main page.  In that file I saved:

```
123 
{{editJobForm}} 
123
```

If I go to it's url, which happens to be, jobs/editjob. It correctly renders 123 (the actual form) 123. (But only if I pass a known pk rather than an ajaxed pk in my view)

When I then try to `{% include "editjob.html" %}` it only includes '123 123'.

I'd rather not approach the problem via my 2nd approach as it seems messy and unclear to anyone else.

Comment: you should edit first and publish a question...

Comment: Somehow I accidentally published it way before I was finished. I'm done now.